# How to Print Out In A Loop?

Tags: clojure

I am learning clojure and I am not sure why this

```clj
(defn repeat-hello []
  (map println (repeat 10 "Hello"))
  (println "The end"))
```

is not printing out `Hello` ten times and `The end`

Answer (score 2):

Strongly recommend reading more about the [lazy sequence](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/laziness.html) and how it works

There are a lot of ways to do it, one of them is using **dotimes** that run something "n" times according to your decision, for example:

`(dotimes [n 3] (println "Hello"))`

Here we basically say:

- dotimes (the name of function)
- [n 3] (which n starts from 0 to 3)
- (println "Hello") (what do you want to execute)

Answer (score 0):

@akond already explained the mystery of the lazy sequence "gotcha", but just to note that if you're forcing a lazy sequence to be realized, you probably didn't want a lazy sequence in the first place. Clojure functions like `dotimes` and `doseq` may be more what you are looking for in situations like this.

```
(defn repeat-hello []
  (dotimes [_ 10]
    (println "Hello"))
  (println "The end"))
```

```
(defn repeat-hello []
  (doseq [s (repeat 10 "Hello")]
    (println s))
  (println "The end"))
```